# Mezzanine and get_FOO_display

Tags: django, mezzanine

I recently upgraded from Django Mezzanine from 1.4 to 3.1.4. The transition has been smooth except an error with models which extend the Mezzanine Page class. When I call the get_FOO_display property on any choice field, I get the short name with `&` between each character. For instance, if I have the test class:

```
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page

class TestModel(Page):
    CHOICES = (
        ('ab', "Aardvarks and Bubblegum"),
        ('cd', "Coocoos and Diphtheria"),
    )

    prop = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CHOICES)
```

I get the following in the Django shell:

```
In [1]: from project.models import TestModel

In [2]: test = TestModel(prop="ab")

In [3]: test.get_prop_display()
Out[3]: u'a & b'
```

If I my model simply extends `models.Model` instead of `Page`, `get_prop_display()` works as expected and I get `Out[3]: Aardvarks and Bubblegum`

Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**
It has been fixed.

---

Ref to [the code](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/db72112976ee024210b9eaf2192ab47d3812c543/mezzanine/core/fields.py#L115):

```
def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
    def _get_FIELD_display(self, field):
        value = getattr(self, field.attname)
        value = force_text(" & ".join([dict(field.choices).get(v, v)
                                       for v in value]), strings_only=True)
        return value
    setattr(cls, '_get_FIELD_display', _get_FIELD_display)

    super(MultiChoiceField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)
```

`MultiChoiceField` unconditionally overrides the `_get_FIELD_display` method of the model it resides in. In your code, that model is `Page` and the field is `Page.in_menus`.

Comparing with [Django's logic](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9d8c73f6a1c636853a5c5013f21985d702b2301b/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L577), the above code may cause incorrect behavior when `Page` or `MultiChoiceField` is used in your model.

<del>Perhaps it's a bug, and [here](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/issues/1032) I've raised an issue.</del> It's fixed now.

Comment: @StephenMcDonald Thanks for the rapid response =)